# Dual Laptop Docking Station

Tags: laptop, docking-stations

I have 2 laptops on my desk most of the time and would like them to share a dock providing video, usb devices and network.  The laptops are both windows machines.

I only use one at a time.

I have 2 X 2k monitors running.

Does such a product exist, or do I need a usb-c switch that takes 1 input and offers 2 outputs.